How can I merge table column cells in a .docx table created using Apache POI
I am trying to merge cells in a generated table to have the effect displayed in the image.

How can I merge cells for this purpose in a Java application that uses Apache POI to generate a .docx file? Tried different combinations but did not obtain the expected effect.
Once the cells are merged when a a lengthy text is added it should span all the merged cells' lengths not use one cell area.
Current output

Source Block
// Add Reservation Details Header
            XWPFParagraph reservationDetailsHeader = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun reservationDetailsRun = reservationDetailsHeader.createRun();
            reservationDetailsRun.setText("Reservation Details");
            reservationDetailsRun.setFontFamily("DejaVu Serif");
            reservationDetailsRun.setFontSize(12);
            reservationDetailsRun.setBold(true);

         // Add a line space below the header
            addLineSpace(document);

         // Create a new table for Reservation Details
            XWPFTable reservationDetailsTable = document.createTable();

         // First row with four columns
            XWPFTableRow reservationRow1 = reservationDetailsTable.getRow(0);
            reservationRow1.getCell(0).setText("Check-In Date:");
            reservationRow1.getCell(1).setText("2024-12-20"); // Sample date
            reservationRow1.getCell(2).setText("No Of Nights :");
            reservationRow1.getCell(3).setText("1");

         // Second row with four columns
            XWPFTableRow reservationRow2 = reservationDetailsTable.createRow();
            reservationRow2.getCell(0).setText("Check-Out Date:");
            reservationRow2.getCell(1).setText("2024-12-22"); // Sample date
            reservationRow2.getCell(2).setText("No Of Rooms :");
            reservationRow2.getCell(3).setText("1");
            
         // Third row with 2 columns
            XWPFTableRow reservationRow3 = reservationDetailsTable.createRow();
            reservationRow3.getCell(0).setText("Room Type Per Rate:");
            
            reservationRow3.getCell(4).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(5));
            reservationRow3.getCell(3).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
            reservationRow3.getCell(2).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
            reservationRow3.getCell(1).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            reservationRow3.getCell(1).setText("Traditional Room (max occ. 2) - 1 King/Static");

Dependencies
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version> <!-- Compatible version for POI 5.2.3 -->
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.20.0</version> <!-- Replace with your required version -->
</dependency>

